# Ruby on Rails Active Record: chaining together 3 methods does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm a student working on a Rails project. I set up the table relationships as shown in the diagram (I think!).

Basically, a Group has many Projects, and a Project has many tasks.

using generic variable names, I was able to get `group.projects` and `projects.tasks` to work, but not `group.tasks`. Is this possible? What am I missing?

Any help would be so much appreciated. Just in case, here are my models (I removed all 'User' info as it is not relevant):

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :projects
  has_many :tasks, through: :projects
end

class Project < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :group
  has_many :tasks
end

class Task < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
end
```

[image: Table Relationships]

Is `group.tasks` possible?

Comment: I figured it out. I needed to change the relationships in the models, and also add a "has_one through" relationship to Task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this should work out of the box.

One of the better ways to find this out is to look at the sql that is generated from a query like that and see if it jives with what you are wanting.  I cleaned this up a little bit but looks exactly like what you are wanting.

```
irb(main):> Group.first.tasks.to_sql
  Group Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "groups".* FROM "groups" ORDER BY "groups"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=>  SELECT "tasks".* FROM "tasks" 
    INNER JOIN "projects" 
      ON "tasks"."project_id" = "projects"."id" 
    WHERE "projects"."group_id" = 1"
```